# Click event using .append() works but fails using .after()

Tags: jquery

Pretty green on this. Any ideas why this works:

```
$('.myclass div').append(' <a ">HELLO WORLD</a>').click(this.function);
```

and this doesn't:

```
$('.myclass div').after(' <a ">HELLO WORLD</a>').click(this.function);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases, you're adding the handler to the `div` that was originally selected. Because events bubble, the first one will still work even tough the handler is on the parent of the `<a>`.

If you want the `a` element after the `div`, you need to bind directly to the `a`.

You can use `.insertAfter()` instead to accomplish this...

```
$('<a>HELLO WORLD</a>').insertAfter('.myclass div').click(this.function);
```

Comment: Just in case, here's the difference between `.after()` and `.insertAfter()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908229/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-insertafter

Comment: You can also use `end()` like `$('.myclass div').after(' <a ">HELLO WORLD</a>').end().click(this.function);`

Comment: @elclanrs: Sort of. If you use `.end()` right there, you're still working with the original jQuery object from `$('.myclass div')`, so it appears as though `.end()` gives you the context, which in this case is the `HTMLDocument`, so that's what gets the `click` handler.